# Redis Sorted Set - command to retrieve members scored lower and higher than member at once

Tags: redis, sortedset

Following commands will get me up to 3 members scored higher and up to 5 member scored lower than member with score 100.

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE key -inf 100 limit 1 5 WITHSCORES
ZRANGEBYSCORE key 100 limit 1 3 WITHSCORES
```

Is there a way, without scripting, to get the data atomically from redis with only one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way, without scripting, to get the data atomically from redis with only one command?

"without scripting" - yes, you can use a transaction (`MULTI/EXEC` block).

"only one command" - no, unless you want to develop a Redis module that implements that logic.